# Xml Serialization + Dynamic Element Name

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I want to know if it is possible to change the element name base on some condition... something like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName=BaseEntity.useShortTag==false?"a0912":"Product")]
public class Product : ONIX.Entities.BaseEntity
{
    public Product()
    {

    }

    public string RecordReference { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible using attributes because they are evaluated at compile time. The only way to achieve this is to make your class implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and handle the serialization manually.